# Positioning elements with CSS

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I know it is dumb question, but i am struggling with following problem
[image]

It is one of my menu buttons. I want `div` the represents icon (marked red with circle) be on the left side of the button and the text on the right (name (blue) above description (purple)). By the way, i am going to have plenty of those buttons and i want them appear in column (block).

My current problem is that icon `div` (red) and text `div` (green dashed) wont place inline.
My HTML is:

```html
<style>
    .HomeMenuNavbarButton {
        text-decoration: none;
        color : black;
        border-style:outset;
        border-width:4px;
        border-radius:15px;
        display:block;
        padding:4px;
    }
    .circle {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
        -moz-border-radius: 25px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        border-color: black;
        border-style: dashed;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            @foreach (var node in Model.Nodes)
            {
                if (!(node.IsRootNode) && node.Children.Any())
                {
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button type="button" style="display:inline;" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="@("#relatedNavList" + node.Title) ">@node.Title</button>
                    <div id="@("relatedNavList" + node.Title)" class="collapse">
                            @foreach (var child in node.Children)
                            {
                                <div class="HomeMenuNavbarButton" style="display:block;">
                                    <div style="background-color:red;display:inline">
                                        <div class="circle">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="border-color: green; border-style: dashed; display:inline-block">
                                        <div style="background-color:blue">@(child.Title)</div>
                                        <div style="background-color:purple">@(child.Description)</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide you generated markup instead of server code? Then after you'll get a solution you should adjust corresponding markup back to razor code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to display stuff side by side in **CSS**, the easiest way is to use *flexbox*. Try to add `display : flex;` to your `HomeMenuNavBar` class.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) is a complete document about *flexbox* from the Mozilla team.

Answer (score 0):

Using a wrapper defined as a flexbox

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 150px;
}

.circle {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: medium dashed darkgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

button {
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: thin solid lightblue;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>Button</button>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is isn't it the same what Louis suggested?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that just with display:inline-block on your button's elements

```css
.elementButton
{
  display:inline-block;
}

.circle {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: dashed;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.HomeMenuNavbarButton
{
  display:block;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="HomeMenuNavbarButton">

    <div class="circle elementButton">
    </div>

    <div class="elementButton">
        <div>Title one</div>
        <div>Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="HomeMenuNavbarButton">

    <div class="circle elementButton">
    </div>

    <div class="elementButton">
        <div >Title two</div>
        <div>Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```